# Hyperledger Fabric ACL in configtx.yaml

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

Please have a look into my issue .I am using hyperledger fabric 1.2 . I am exploring `ACL` at the time of channel creation. I just copied default `Writers` Policy and rename it with `PankajPolicy` and put into the Channel.Application in configtx.yaml [see here](https://hastebin.com/hutodazeco.coffeescript).

Now the issue is that I just replaced `peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers` With PankajPolicy in `peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/PankajPoilicy`. For complete configtx.yaml please have a look [see here](https://hastebin.com/aqusaroher.coffeescript).

When i create genesis block with this and trying to create the channel evrything goes fine .But at the time of query am getting error

```
Error: error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy [/Channel/Application/PankajPoilicy]: [policy /Channel/Application/PankajPoilicy not found] - proposal response: <nil>
```

Instead if something is wrong then it should stop on write operation means at the time of `peer chaincode instansiate`.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your own policy. So according to the comment on sample configtx.yaml

```
Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
```

Your custom defined policy will be accessible on this path `/Channel/<PolicyName>`

Please use this `peer/Propose: /Channel/PankajPoilicy`
instead of this 
`peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/PankajPoilicy`

I do not know why your write operations are working with the current configuration.

Comment: currently everything is fine but previously why it is not stopping me on `peer chaincode instansiate` . Because policy path was not correct and i applied the policy on `peer/propose` .